# How do I add a stopwatch to this program?

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.3

How do I find the time I have used, and refresh after the ball touches the bottom? The code is:

```
from tkinter import *
import random
import time

class Ball:
    def __init__(self, canvas, paddle, color):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.paddle = paddle

        self.id = canvas.create_oval(10, 10, 25, 25, fill=color)

        starts = [-3, -2, -1, 1, 2, 3]
        random.shuffle(starts)

        self.x = starts[0]
        self.y = -3
        self.canvas_height = canvas.winfo_height()
        self.canvas_width = canvas.winfo_width()

        self.is_hitting_bottom = False

        canvas.move(self.id, 245, 100)

    def draw(self):
        self.canvas.move(self.id, self.x, self.y)

        pos = self.canvas.coords(self.id)

        if pos[1] <= 0:
            self.y = 1

        if pos[3] >= self.canvas_height:
            # self.y = -1
            self.is_hitting_bottom = True

        if self.hit_top_paddle(pos) == True:
            self.y = -3

        if self.hit_bottom_paddle(pos) == True:
            self.y = 1

        if pos[0] <= 0:
            self.x = 3

        if pos[2] >= self.canvas_width:
            self.x = -3

    def hit_top_paddle(self, pos):
        paddle_pos = self.canvas.coords(self.paddle.id)
        if pos[2] >= paddle_pos[0] and pos[0] <= paddle_pos[2]:
            if pos[3] >= paddle_pos[1] and pos[3] <= paddle_pos[3]:
                return True

            return False

    def hit_bottom_paddle(self, pos):
            paddle_pos = self.canvas.coords(self.paddle.id)
            if pos[2] >= paddle_pos[0] and pos[0] <= paddle_pos[2]:
                if pos[1] >= paddle_pos[1] and pos[1] <= paddle_pos[3]:
                        return True

            return False

class Paddle:
    def __init__(self, canvas, color):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.id = canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, 100, 10, fill=color)

        self.x = 0
        self.canvas_width = canvas.winfo_width()

        canvas.move(self.id, 200, 300)

        canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-Left>', self.move_left)
        canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-Right>', self.move_right)

    def draw(self):
        self.canvas.move(self.id, self.x, 0)

        pos = self.canvas.coords(self.id)

        if pos[0] <= 0:
            self.x = 0

        if pos[2] >= self.canvas_width:
            self.x = 0

    def move_left(self, event):
        self.x = -2

    def move_right(self, event):
        self.x = 2

tk = Tk()
tk.title('Game')
canvas = Canvas(tk, width=550, height=400, bd=0, highlightthickness=0)
canvas.pack()
tk.update()

paddle = Paddle(canvas, 'blue')
ball = Ball(canvas, paddle, 'red')

while 1:
    if ball.is_hitting_bottom == False:
        ball.draw()
        paddle.draw()

    tk.update_idletasks()
    tk.update()
    time.sleep(0.01)
```

It should give me a request to change or not... So, if I have used x minutes and the ball touches the bottom, it should ask me whether I want to [lay again or note...

Comment: Hint: store the current time returned by the function `time.time()` or `time.clock()`.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest answer in your case is

```
import time

start_time= time.clock()
... code to time ...
elapsed_time= time.clock() - start_time
```

If I understand correctly the intended logic, this can be integrated with your program's main loop in the following way:

```
import time
play_again= 1
while play_again:
    start_time= time.clock()
    while 1:
        if ball.is_hitting_bottom == False:
            ball.draw()
            paddle.draw()
        else:
            if time.clock() - start_time > 60: break
        tk.update_idletasks()
        tk.update()
        time.sleep(0.01)
    # Ask user if to play again and leave boolean result in variable play_again
```

Comment: can you please cut and paste it in the program up there? i dont get your reference to the main loop

Comment: It's the last 8 lines of the code you posted, starting with `while 1:`.

Comment: What is not working?  Please consider that you asked about adding a stopwatch.  I did not review any other part of the logic.  In particular, this depends on `ball.is_hitting_bottom` getting to be True at some point.

Comment: The stopwatch is not coming up, Mario!

Comment: Any help will be appreciated, Mario!